Vendor directory changes not working
I know changes in vendor directory should not be done but I need to do some debugging. I am using a https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento in which I am using Magento on docker. If I override any file then its working but same file I try to make any changes its not. I had added this thing in their repo too but they deleted it. May be they don't have answers or don't want to solve this problem.

By default, docker-magento does not support bi-directional sync for the entire project source code due to performance reasons. However, it does bi-directionally sync the folders that you work with the most, such as app/code and app/design, out of the box. All the files it syncs are listed under the config node services > app > volumes in the compose.dev.yaml file.
If you are running Linux, as it does not have performance issues with syncing the entire project source code, you can copy compose.dev-linux.yml to compose.dev.yml to enable Docker to sync the entire project source code between the host and the container. This information is already mentioned in the docker-magento repository at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento?tab=readme-ov-file#linux.
Otherwise, whenever you modify vendor files from your host, you will need to copy them to the Docker container using the custom CLI command bin/copytocontainer.
For example:

Copy a file: bin/copytocontainer vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php
Copy a folder: bin/copytocontainer vendor/magento/module-cms


Can you also help with logs? I am unable to see logs written

You can utilize the bin/log custom CLI, which monitors the Magento log files. Pass no params to tail all files. For a specific log file, add the appropriate log filename, e.g., bin/log debug.log. I highly recommend reading the instructions from the docker-magento GitHub repo as it provides a lot of useful information.
Additionally, you can drop into the bash prompt of your phpfpm Docker container by running the custom CLI bin/bash and check the logs there. Moreover, you can copy the log folder from the container to your host using bin/copyfromcontainer var/log

Hi thanks it really helped.

You're most welcome!

How should I do it permanently?
